# How to return dynamic table with Max Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep a log where I enter Job, Description, TC Code, Units, Date Requested, and Requester. From here I need to return each Job, along with each distinct TC code (which will continue to grow) and the rest of the information where the date requested is the Max Date.

EX Log:

```
Job  Desc  TC CODE  Units   Date     Rqstr
17   MCD    Days     5     4/1/19    Fred
20   BK     Days     10    4/1/19    John
17   MCD    Crew     8     4/2/19    Bob
33   WEN    Days     10    4/1/19    Dave
40   ARB    Crew     7     4/3/19    Jim
40   ARB    Hours    10    4/3/19    Jim
17   MCD    Days     10    4/5/19    Tim
17   MCD    Con      5     4/5/19    Tim
20   BK     Days     8     4/8/19    Tye
20   BK     Crew     3     4/8/19    Tye
17   MCD    Crew     5     4/8/19    Tim
```

I tried Row Number, but I can not really partition TC code because I need every distinct code, per job as well. Partitioning will only return distinct TC codes, and list the Jobs where the date is the max date

```
select [Job],
  [Description],
  [TC Code],
  [Units],
  [Date Requested],
  [Requestor]

from (Select [Job],
  [Description],
  [TC Code],
  [Units],
  [Date Requested],
  [Requestor],
       row_number() over(partition by [TC Code] order by [Date Requested] 
desc) as rn
  from [dbo].['VAR ADJ Log$']) as t

where rn = 1
```

The result I need:

I need to return every distinct TC Code with the latest date, per job. As you can see on Job 17 a new TC Code was introduced and added, and the Crew TC code was replaced with the most recent.

```
Job  Desc  TC CODE  Units   Date     Rqstr
17   MCD    Days     10    4/5/19    Tim
17   MCD    Crew     5     4/8/19    Tim
17   MCD    Con      5     4/5/19    Tim
20   BK     Days     8     4/8/19    Tye
20   BK     Crew     3     4/8/19    Tye 
33   WEN    Days     10    4/1/19    Dave
40   ARB    Crew     7     4/3/19    Jim
40   ARB    Hours    10    4/3/19    Jim
```

Comment: You can have more than one column in the `PARTITION BY` clause, so would `PARTITION BY Job, [TC CODE] {, Others?}` not work?

Comment: Thank you so much @Larnu ! This worked. I was not aware of multiple partition columns. Life Saver!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select val.*
from [dbo].['VAR ADJ Log$'] val
where val.date = (select max(val2.date)
                  from [dbo].['VAR ADJ Log$'] val2
                  where val2.job = val.job and val2.[TC Code] = val2.[TC Code]
                 );
```

You can also do this with window functions (although there is probably no particular advantage).  This seems to be the logic you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff. I did not have a chance to try this. I was not aware of defining multiple partition columns, and that worked. – Joey B 13 mins ago     Delete